# Layers for predicting financial data using Tensorflow/tflearn

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, financial, tflearn

I'd like to predict the  interest rate and I've got some relevant factors like stock index and money supply number, something like that. The number of factors may be up to 200.

For example,the training data like, X contains factors and y is the interest rate I want to train and predict.

```
     factor1      factor2     factor3          factor176  factor177    factor178
X= [[ 2.1428      6.1557      5.4101     ...,  5.86        6.0735      6.191 ]
    [ 2.168       6.1533      5.2315     ...,  5.8185      6.0591      6.189 ]
    [ 2.125       4.7965      3.9443     ...,  5.7845      5.9873      6.1283]...]

y= [[ 3.5593]
    [ 3.014 ]
    [ 2.7125]...]
```

So I want to use tensorflow/tflearn to train this model but I don't really know what method exactly I should choose to do regression. I have tried LinearRegression from tflearn before, but the result is not so great.

For now, I just use the code I found online.

```
net = tflearn.input_data([None, 178])
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 64, activation='linear',
                                weight_decay=0.0005)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 1, activation='linear')
net = tflearn.regression(net, optimizer=
tflearn.optimizers.AdaGrad(learning_rate=0.01, initial_accumulator_value=0.01), 
loss='mean_square', learning_rate=0.05)
model = tflearn.DNN(net, tensorboard_verbose=0, checkpoint_path='tmp/')
model.fit(X, y, show_metric=True,
            batch_size=1, n_epoch=100)
```

The result is roughly 50% accuracy when the error range is ±10%.
I have tried to make the window to 7 days but the result is still bad. So I want to know what additional layer I can use to make this network better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all this network makes no sense. If you do not have any activations on your hidden units, you network is **equivalent to linear regression**.

So first of all change

```
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 64, activation='linear',
                                weight_decay=0.0005)
```

to

```
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 64, activation='relu',
                                weight_decay=0.0005)
```

Another general thing is to **always** normalise your data. Your X's are big, y's are big as well - make sure they aren't, by for example whitening them (making them 0 mean and 1 std).

Finding right architecture is hard problem and you will not find any "magical recipies" for that. Start with understanding what you are doing. Log your training, see if the training loss converges to small values, if it does not - you either do not train long enough, network is too small, or training hyperparameters are off (like too big learning right, too high regularisation etc.)

Comment: My current version :[code&dataset](https://www.floydhub.com/asdasdad/projects/a/4/code)  I've tried the relu but the result of the test data seems weird.  The output: [output](https://www.floydhub.com/viewer/data/TXCRxgLTngd788FeLA4YQU/)

Comment: as said in the answer - linear activation is a **mistake**, but making things work require actually understanding data and model; the linear thing is the only actual "bug", everything else is a matter of doing step by step analysis and looking where things go wrong - and again - looking into **training** is crucial, not test at this point

Comment: I mean if I change all 'linear' to 'relu' the output of y is still the same mostly, and I am really confused because I use the same data using linear to predict stock index the accuracy is pretty good, I don't get why the interest rate is so different.

Comment: you are not supposed to change **all** linear, only the one pointed out in the answer.